# Chrome extension javascript, change selected text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

im writing an extension to Chrome and i cant figure out how to change on click selected text inside textarea to something else.

I was looking for some answers but all of them are for the situation where we know the id of the textarea, then we look for it with getElementById so we can change its content.

I am looking for solution that would work on any website that use textareas. This is my current code:

```
function encrypt(info,tab) {
cryptoProperties = sjcl.encrypt("password", info.selectionText);
encoded_cryptoProperties = window.btoa("abcd");  
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
title: "encrypt: %s", 
contexts:["selection"], 
onclick: encrypt,
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, a `<textarea>` is an editable element already. Why do you think you need an extension to change selected text? Just use your clipboard to paste and replace the selected text...

Comment: I want to select text, encrypt it on click, and than swap it.

Comment: encrypt it how? Do you have a preset key stored somewhere? It would have been nice to mention that in your question, but it already sounds like this is much too broad.

Comment: Is it even relevant? Im using sjcl library. I already have encryption of selected text i just dont know how to swap it.

Comment: Yes it is relevant, because without sharing your existing code you have so far, it sounds like you're asking stackoverflow to write a project for you for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working demo, excluding the encryption:

```js
// this will replace selected text immediately.
// A more user-friendly approach would be to process selected text here
// and then actually replace it after some sort of user-confirmation
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  let element = document.activeElement;

  if (element instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) {
    let {selectionStart, selectionEnd} = element;

    // nothing is selected
    if (selectionStart === selectionEnd) return;

    let string = element.value;
    let prefix = string.substring(0, selectionStart);
    let infix = string.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    let postfix = string.substring(selectionEnd);

    element.value = prefix + 'REPLACED TEXT' + postfix;
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea cols="80" rows="10">Highlight me!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
```

Comment: document.addEventListener doesn't seem to work, even when i just put there only alert("alert"). Any idea?

Comment: You have to get the `window` object of the tab the context menu is on and then do `tabWindow.document.addEventListener(...)` but that is beyond the context of this question.